# gsd-media-keys: Failed to save a screenshot: Timeout was reached Unable to save ubuntu 18.10 screenshot

Tags: gnome, keyboard, screenshot

Can anyone help me? My Ubuntu 18.10 can't take any screenshot with PrtSc keyboard button. After i push the PrtSc button, the gnome freeze. After some sec, gnome-shell restart itself. This is syslog after i push the button https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d693V9BBY7/. However, i can take screenshot with flameshot app. But sometime stock gnome screenshot tool is needed.

Thanks